# Efficient method to read excel file in C#

Tags: c#, excel, file

I want to read a huge excel file workbooks and I also want to modify some of the lines in the workbook.

Readying and saving through structures is complicated process, is there any other alternative efficient method?

Comment: How does your "inefficient" method look like?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you trying to read/write new xlsx format or older xls?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your idea of »huge« looks like, but previously I used [NativeExcel](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcelnet/index.htm) to access and create Excel files. It's a *lot* faster than the normal Excel API.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best to go with OLEDB or http://openexcel.codeplex.com/.

You can choose either of them. More details can be found at.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB

http://openexcel.codeplex.com/

OpenExcel is open source and cool library.